# How do we can get story insights of Instagram with graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I want to get Instagram stories insights which published in the last 24 hours. I currently only access to story basic details alike, story image, owner id, etc with this api:

> https://graph.facebook.com/story_id/?fields=id,media_type,media_url,owner,timestamp,caption&access_token={access_token}

Actually i want to get all details which is that: exits,impressions,reach,replies,taps_forward,taps_back

but  when I try this with this api:

> https://graph.facebook.com/story_id/insights?metric=exits,impressions,reach,replies,taps_forward,taps_back&access_token={access_token}

it show me that error. always.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) Not enough viewers for the media to show insights",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "AvZdhqaXB1_Dij7B1DD-pSR"
   }
}
```

even that on reference of graph api they tell us do same like :
Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights#create

I dont know how to fill butt it shows me error always

https://i.stack.imgur.com/55rBy.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a webhook for it:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/webhooks/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started

Your webhook URL will get the insights of a story (or media object, to be specific) right when it disappears, with a POST request from Instagram.

Careful though, you cannot access the story details anymore if you get the webhook, so you have to get the stories when they exist (for example, with a cron job that runs at least every 23h to get all stories) and add the insights data later by matching the media id.

Comment: Can you please share any doc or video how webhook working,i tried last time but unable to create webhook. Actually don know about it..Kindly share any reference link. also have any suitable link to get stories insights.Thanks

Comment: there is a very detailed step by step explanation in the docs, just follow the links in my answer. i have added another one.

Comment: ok thanks let me check in once.i have Actual issue to subscribe webhook.

Comment: hy Can you please clear me this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/55rBy.png  i dont know how to fill it i am trying to do it but not success.

Comment: did you read all the information in the links of my answer? there is example code too, you have to set up the webhook one time, facebook will contact your callback url and compare the verify token with a GET request. of course you have to set this up on your server first. i suggest using node.js, because that's the example code.

Comment: but i am using php Codeigniter. Ok let me set my server link first. One more last thing if i set for instagram stories then it will show me stories of mine or user who login in to Facebook or What? i read whol documentation but no where its mention.

Comment: of course you can also use php, it does not matter. it is a simple GET request to set up the webhook, and POST requests to handle submissions.

Comment: if you set up a webhook for stories, you will ONLY get insights of that story, with a media id. the story will be gone by that time, so make sure you get all the stories on a regular basis. compare the media id of the webhook to your stored stories. of course you only get stories of a specific IG business account, connected to a facebook page you manage.